# Are there community detection algorithms where number of communities is specified in advance?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, references, social-network

I want to detect specific number of communities in networks, which require algorithms, where number of communities are specified in advance. Also if there are any, I would like to know how to implement (R, Python).

Comment: Please have a look at the ['How to ask'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Your question is quite broad and could possibly be narrowed down.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the number of communities contradicts the quality.

Assuming you have 5 disconnected components, but insist on 4 communities, the algorithm would have to randomly merge 2 disconnected parts.

Most users will not be accepting such a loss in quality, so you will need to implement such a variant yourself. Please begin writing code, and update your question with code when you are having issues.